# jqplot start graph axis labelling from top

Tags: javascript, charts, jqplot

Want a simple fix for jqplot axis display. I am using Bubble charts for chart display, and CategoryAxisRenderer for axis.

> All I want is the axes to display in top-down fashion, rather than the default bottom-up one. **Meaning**, the **x axis is displayed on top of the chart increasing from left to right, and the y axis starts from the top increasing from top to bottom!!**

Have looked in for various in-built jqplot options but to no luck. I am afraid that the solution lies in altering the css definitions for jqplot axis, but i do not want that, as it would consume huge amounts of time just to understand someone else's css. Please if someone could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have got my solution finally.

1. Reversed the array that had to be printed row wise, hence both chart and the y axis came up correctly.
2. The second x axis , did not solve my problem. Instead for the particular chart id ,  modified the the css class jqplot-xaxis and that did the trick.

   myBubbleChartId .jqplot-xaxis{

   ```
   position : absolute;
   top : -20px !important;
   ```

   }